# Unreachable code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I am "attempting" to make an android app. I am trying to make it so that when I click on a button it'll take me to another layout. I've done everything else correctly, I am pretty sure... 0 errors apart from this one. Unreachable code.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;


Button bUtuube = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Utuube);
bUtuube.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

I am getting the unreachable code error at `Button bUtuube = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Utuube)`. Thats where the red line appears.

Cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `return true;` causes you to exit the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method and return control to the caller. So the compiler is trying to tell you is that there is no way to get to the code after the return statement.

Comment: OK thanks. I tried to delete it, that came up with unreachable code, so i tried to make it return; false. that came up with errors too... Any idea? (Sorry if i am annoying you with noob questions)

Comment: don't return there, only at the end of the function.

Comment: @user2154615 What are you trying to do with that method?  A simple fix would be to move the return true; to the bottom of the method right before the closing brace }.  But I do not know how that affects the rest of your code.

Comment: Ah, there are 2 `return true;` statements, just delete the higher up one! Thanks, totally worked. `Return` should come last (and only one `return`). ;)

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the closing brace:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

} // < ----- missing

Button bUtuube = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Utuube);
bUtuube.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

It's impossible to tell from the fragment you have shown, but I am assuming that the YouTube  button should be declared outside `onCreateOptionsMenu` which seems likely.

Comment: Ah, a downvote with no comment.  Thank you.  I'd be interested to know why since this a perfectly possible solution for the code fragment shown in the OP.